# Spy utility for Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, utility, spy

I've used [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com), it is the brilliant tool for WPF. [SilverlightSpy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/) has similar functionality for Silverlight and WP7. Does anybody know about any similar tools for Windows 8 projects?

**EDIT :** I mean Windows Metro style applications on C#/XAML that run in Simulator or Local Machine.

Comment: The question is not detailed enough. What's a "Windows 8 project?" There are *many* different frameworks/platforms/building blocks to make metro-style apps.

Comment: Thanks for your note. I've added details. Hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've heard (and according to [these](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winappswithcsharp/thread/a5085cb8-8e1c-49e4-bacb-94266dc1113c) [posts](https://twitter.com/timheuer/status/195586392913494017)), there really isn't a good way to do that yet.  Supposedly it's coming with the next version.  [Semi-functional way to debug bindings now.](http://www.kelvinhammered.com/?p=150)

Comment: Thanks. I will look for final version. Thanks for link to debug binding.

Comment: Moreover, I've found this utility XamlSpy (http://xamlspy.com/). Pre-release version is free for current moment and I need add some code to force it works - http://xamlspy.com/learn/tutorials/connect/winrt

Comment: XAML Spy works *very* nicely for Windows 8 Store Apps. Well worth the money.